# Compiler behaviour for Length(Static Array)

Tags: delphi

I have micro-optimization issue

```
const Max=100;
var Arr:array[0..Max-1] of Integer; // I change to zero based
```

Code 1:

```
Writeln(Length(Arr));
```

Code 2

```
Writeln(Max);
```

can Delphi compiler changes Code #1 to Code #2 . yes or no?

Comment: What is your question. The length of a 1-based array is  indeed the index of the last value. It's quite likely that your attempts to optimise are making matters worse.

Comment: @J... What is the question then? Can you phrase it in a way that we can understand?

Comment: @J... There's no obvious question here. We need to get askers to ask clear questions for everyone's benefit. Where micro optimisation comes in to this is a mystery.

Comment: my internal functions have so many memory allocation. delphi compiler can be convert `Length(StaticArr)` to  `Max` for optimise native code?

Comment: @Majid Please edit the question to make it clear what your issue is. We can't understand your question. Are you asking if the compiler evaluates `Length(...)` at compile time for static arrays.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan ,I am sure in dynamic array computing length must be `RTL` function but I am sure for static array is

Comment: Please edit the question as I asked. If the language is too hard for you then I'll do it for you.

Comment: I asked (and answered) the question that I believe you are asking: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31653170/when-is-length-evaluated-for-a-static-array

Comment: This is better.  The answer is that `Code1` and `Code2` are exactly the same.  Put a breakpoint and push `CTRL+Alt+C` - you'll see they both produce identical assembly :  `mov eax,[$005e9bb4];mov edx,$00000064;call @Write0Long;call @WriteLn`  In particular, note `mov edx,$00000064` - the compiler has indeed transformed this into a compile-time constant for `Length(Arr)`.

Comment: @J... Now I guess you can see that the unclear close vote was the correct one

Comment: @DavidHeffernan Indeed, I concede.

Comment: @Majid Thanks for the edit. I think my other Q&A deal with this. Right?