# When is Length evaluated for a static array?

Tags: delphi

```
type
  TMyArray = array [0..255] of Integer;

var
  Arr: TMyArray;

....

Writeln(Length(Arr));
```

When is `Length()` evaluated in this context, when passed a static array? Is it evaluated at runtime, or at compile time?

Comment: @TLama Thanks. I searched for a dupe but searched concentrating on the static array compile time issue. That dupe question has a lovely answer from Rob.

Comment: I asked this question ,please open it http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31650906/compiler-behaviour-for-lengthstatic-array

Comment: @Majid No. It's a duplicate of this question and others. You have your answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> When is `Length()` evaluated in this context, when passed a static array?

It is evaluated at compile time, and therefore carries no runtime overhead.